# mockito - faking addObserver

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, observable

I am beginning with mockito and wondering how to fake adding an observer. I want to write a test that ensures that the observer count has increased after a function call.

example testing code:

```
MyClassUnderTest instance = new MyClassUnderTest();
AudioDeviceManager adm = mock(AudioDeviceManager.class);

assertEquals(adm.countObservers(), 0);

instance.setup(adm, microphone);
//Inside the setup function, microphone is added as an observer 
//to the device manager: adm.addObserver(microphone);

assertEquals(adm.countObservers(), 1);
```

Since adm is a mock, I know I have to define the logic of `addObserver` but I do not know what to -
`when(adm.addObserver(Observer o)).then(?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

brian,

use verify. For example instead of the assert, run

```
verify(adm).countObservers( AnyObject)
```

and check the first chapter of http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Cheers,
a.

Comment: thanks! I am not sure how I learned some things about mockito while missing the first topics. I will give that a read.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing MyClassUnderTest then you shouldn't be caring what adm does. Write a separate set of test cases for AudioDeviceManager where it isn't mocked.